# How can I find the film speed and type of unmarked, exposed120 film?

Tags: film

I have several rolls of exposed 120 film from a trip, some of the rolls are black and white and some are color, and the speed range from 100 to 800. I would like to get the film developed, but I cant remember which roll is which. Is there any way I can determine what kind of film each of these rolls actually are, or do I just have to guess?

Answer (score 2):

The lab should be able to deduce this, just give them a heads up that theres a mix of colour and b&w but you arent sure which.

Not sure if its all film but most b&w i've shot had black backing paper but i believe tmax is orange like most kodaks.

Try googling any numbers/letters you can find on the paper backing

Answer (score 1):

Are these 120 roll film with paper backing? The backing should be a clue -- if the name of the film isn't written, the color may differ for different emulsions. One might need to spool the film, in a darkroom or darkbox, back to the beginning, for a printed ID. Hopefully, there was a better ID than just a label that was removed.